# Creating a dictionary of three word phrases based on input

Tags: python, input, sentence

```
def splitSentence(sentence):
    dictionarySentence = {}
    setence_split = sentence.split()
    three_word_list = [' '.join(setence_split[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(setence_split), 3)]
    #grouped_words = [' '.join(words[i: i + 3]) for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
    for key,char in enumerate(three_word_list):
        {
            dictionaryTweets.update({char:1})
            
        }
    return dictionaryTweets
    return three_word_list
splitSentence("My name is Allen. How are you?")
```

Output:

```
{'My name is': 1, 'Allen. How are': 1, 'you?': 1}
```

Output looking for:

```
{'My name is': 1, 'is Allen. How': 1, 'How are you?': 1}
```

The output should be a dictionary whose keys are all three word phrases based on a sentence inputted into the function. I am not 100% how you would ensure that the phrases are three words long. Could someone assist with this?

Comment: The output you want doesn't seem to have a consistent rule. If the overlap in `'Allen. How are'` and `'How are you?'` is OK, why isn't e.g. `'is Allen. How'` expected?

Comment: You right, my bad. Let me edit the output here. One sec.

Comment: What is supposed to do is have phrases with 3 unique words for each key in the dictionary

Comment: The rule you want is still unclear. Why is ["My name is", "Allen. How are", "How are you"] not an acceptable solution? Do you need one word to overlap between consecutive keys? Your example is of the form `A B C D E F G` and the expected split is [`A B C`; `C D E`; `E F G`]. What is your expected split for the following sentences? `A B C D E F G H I`? `A B C D E F G H`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Function name and definitions are different.
2. You cannot have 2 return statements.
3. `dictionaryTweets` is not defined.

The below code is working fine.

```
def splitTextToTriplet(sentence):
    dictionaryTweets = {}
    three_word_list = []
    setence_split = sentence.split()
    for i in range(0,len(setence_split)-1,2):
        three_word_list.append(' '.join(setence_split[i:i+3]))
    for key, char in enumerate(three_word_list):
            dictionaryTweets.update({char: 1})

    return dictionaryTweets, three_word_list

print(splitTextToTriplet("My name is Allen. How are you?"))
```